# CORS error - Website is not reachable (ERR_FAILED), then redirects and works by itself

Tags: google-chrome, cors, dreamhost

Error: I get "This site can't be reached ..." and then it automatically redirects and then the page works. Please see the screengrab GIF below.

[image]

This error happens in random unpredictable intervals. On average it occurs once in ten times.

It happens even in a plain HTML page where there is no content. I tested with only a "Hello World" text. There are no CSS or other file includes, and no access to third-party websites.

In Chrome Dev Tools, Status says CORS error and then redirects and the page displays.

This is occurring only on the latest Chrome browsers (Chromium: 102.0.5005.) Latest as of the moment.

This issue started from 25-May-2022 which coincides with the date of launch of this Chrome 102.0.5005. I tested on Chrome Beta (103.0.5060 the next version due) and it is reproducible.

The traffic stats from Google Analytics has also dropped by around 20%. This drop started from the same date 25-May-2022.

I checked the hosting server error log and there are no errors. I have hosted all my websites in DreamHost VPS and it occurs in all my websites. I checked a random website (not mine) hosted in DreamHost and can reproduce this issue.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Use latest Chrome browsers (Chrome or Brave) Chromium: 102.0.5005.
2. Go to Website https://www.mattbeno.com/
3. Refresh like around 10 times with a few seconds interval between each refresh.

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Not sure about CORS error but I am getting the "ERR_FAILED" intermittently on DreamHost servers.

I have different domains pointing to the same path in the file system. Not sure if this is causing the problem.

Do you have multiple domains pointing to the same path in filesystem too?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, couriously in a DreamHost server too. It happens in differents computers and different connections. Allways in Chrome.

Comment: I am using DreamHost VPS and have hosted multiple domains on the same server. Kind of shared hosting. Every website has its own separate path in the disk. All the domains are facing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I got a response from DreamHost support stating: There have been reports that there is a bug in the latest version of Chromium, which affects chromium based browsers (Chrome, Edge, etc), where users are randomly getting the "Err-Failed" error and a refresh will resolve it.

They do not have the tracking number for the Chromium bug at this time, however they know a bug was opened with the developers of Chromium.

They also said that if you use a non-chromium based browser like Firefox, the issue does not happen.

Comment: I checked with DreamHost support and they said the same. It is a Chrome specific issue, which it true. But at the same time I suspect that is also occurring 'only' on DreamHost. If it is because of Chrome, why it is not occurring on websites hosted elsewhere. Also I suspect it is happening only on select clusters in DreamHost, otherwise this issue would have received wider attention. I filed a bug with Chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1334689 and it is not progressing at a desired pace. Left with little choice now and need to experiment with other hosting providers.

Comment: @Joseph I have the same feeling. I did not see any reports of this occurring with other hosting companies.  I have two different accounts in DH running on different servers and clusters.  The issue occurs on both accounts/servers.

Comment: I can confirm this bug is solved since Chrome Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (x86_64) (Mac OS)

This update was released at Tuesday, June 21, 2022.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this bug is solved since Chrome Version 103.0.5060.53 (Official Build) (x86_64) (Mac OS)

This update was released at Tuesday, June 21, 2022.

Comment: Why did you post this as a separate answer? You could also edit and update your first answer. This way, all relevant information is kept together and easy to find (especially when more answers might be added in the future).